# Coreldraw VBA adding strings together in color assignment

Tags: vba, string, data-manipulation, coreldraw

Im sure im doing something stupid here but I cant get the following to work. I Have the following line of code

```
ActiveSelectionRange.ApplyCustomHatchFill ANG.value, LS.value, 0, 10, 0, LT.value, CreateRGBColor(255,255,255), Style:=OutlineStyles(TextBox5.value), DashDotLength:=(TextBox6.value), PenWidth:=(TextBox7.value), BackColor:=CreateRGBColor(255, 255, 255)
```

I am trying to replace the following part with variables

```
CreateRGBColor(255,255,255)
```

with the following

```
 a = colbut.BackColor
 R = a Mod 256
 G = Int(a / 256) Mod 256
 B = Int(a / 256 / 256) Mod 256

ActiveSelectionRange.ApplyCustomHatchFill ANG.value, LS.value, 0, 10, 0, LT.value, CreateRGBColor(" & R & ", " & G & ", " & B & ", " & "), Style:=OutlineStyles(TextBox5.value), DashDotLength:=(TextBox6.value), PenWidth:=(TextBox7.value), BackColor:=CreateRGBColor(255, 255, 255)
```

It keeps throwing the error "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

I have tried all variations of adding the strings but to no avail

Any help is greatly appreciated
Mark

Comment: `CreateRGBColor(" & R & ", " & G & ", " & B & ", " & ")` should be `CreateRGBColor(R,  G,  B)` variables on VBA are supposed to be like the number, so you would do as if they were numbers

Comment: Doh!!! told you i was being stupid Thanks for the save